# Model property treated as object instead of string in formatOptions

Tags: sapui5

I have a fragment containing labels and input components. Its values are mostly set statically and it works as expected:

```xml
<Label text="Customer" />
<Input
  value="John Smith"
  editable="true"
  change=".liveChangeVehicleGrossPrice"
/>
<Label text="Price" />
<Input
  editable="true"
  change=".liveChangeVehicleGrossPrice"
  value="{
    parts: [
      'P02_Model>/VehicleGrossPrice',
      'valuta>/convert'
    ],
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
    formatOptions: {
      showMeasure: false
    }
  }"
/>
```

Now I have created in the controller a model containing values to be used in the input components: one value (customer) to be added in the customer name field and two properties (`groupingSeparator` and `decimalSeparator`) for formatting the currency:

```js
var json = {
  "groupingSeparator": " ",
  "decimalSeparator": ",",
  "customer": "John Wayne",
};
var model = new JSONModel(json);
this.getView().setModel(model, "P02_Model");
```

Following the creation of this model, I modify the fragment in order to use these values:

```xml
<Label text="Customer" />
<Input
  editable="true"
  change=".liveChangeVehicleGrossPrice"
  value="{P02_Model>/customer}"
/>
<Label text="Price" />
<Input
  editable="true"
  change=".liveChangeVehicleGrossPrice"
  value="{
    parts: [
      'P02_Model>/VehicleGrossPrice',
      'valuta>/convert'
    ],
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
    formatOptions: {
      showMeasure: false,
      groupingSeparator: {P02_Model>/groupingSeparator},
      decimalSeparator: {P02_Model>/decimalSeparator}
    }
  }"
/>
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded, the name `John Wayne` is correctly mapped in the associated input, but the input containing the currency will have

> 112[Object object]323[Object object]2

instead of `112 323,2`.

Somehow the two values associated with `groupingSeparator` and `decimalSeparator`, which are strings, are treated as objects. WHY?

Comment: I do not think you can set values to groupingSeparator using binding. It has to be a static value. Only properties of a UI5 control can be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHY?

It's because binding info objects are not a ManagedObject but a plain simple object which doesn't support binding capabilities. You'll have to do it in JS.

```xml
<Input id="myInput" />
```

```js
onInit: function() {
  // ...    
  const model = this.getView().getModel("P02_Model");
  this.byId("myInput").bindValue({
    parts: [
      "P02_Model>/VehicleGrossPrice",
      "valuta>/convert"
    ],
    type: this.createCurrencyType()
  });
},

onModelDataChanged: function() {
  this.byId("myInput").getBinding("value").setType(this.createCurrencyType());
},

createCurrencyType: function() {
  return new CurrencyType({ // required "sap/ui/model/type/Currency"
    groupingSeparator: model.getProperty("/groupingSeparator"),
    decimalSeparator: model.getProperty("/decimalSeparator")
  });
},
```